# Make table with monospaced font Wxpython

Tags: python, fonts, wxpython

I am trying to create a table with characters in Wxpython. Something of type:

```
┌─────────┬──────────┐
│columna1 │ columna2 │
├─────────┼──────────┤
│dato1    │ dato2    │
├─────────┼──────────┤
│dato3    │ dato4    │
└─────────┴──────────┘
```

I use the code `dc.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.TELETYPE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))`

But monospaced seems to not apply to the lines in the table and therefore results in something similar to this:

```
┌─────────┬──────────┐
│columna1  │ columna2 │
├─────────┼──────────┤
│dato1      │ dato2    │
├─────────┼──────────┤
│dato3   │ dato4    │
└─────────┴──────────┘
```

I plan to apply the font to text that is going to be sent to a printer. Thank you.

This is an example code that has the error:

```
import wx

class TextDocPrintout(wx.Printout):

    """

    A printout class that is able to print simple text documents.

    Does not handle page numbers or titles, and it assumes that no

    lines are longer than what will fit within the page width.  Those

    features are left as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

    """

    def __init__(self):#, text, title, margins):

        wx.Printout.__init__(self)#, title)

    def HasPage(self, page):

        return page <= self.numPages



    def GetPageInfo(self):

        return (1, self.numPages, 1, self.numPages)

    def CalculateScale(self, dc):

        # Scale the DC such that the printout is roughly the same as

        # the screen scaling.

        ppiPrinterX, ppiPrinterY = self.GetPPIPrinter()

        ppiScreenX, ppiScreenY = self.GetPPIScreen()

        logScale = float(ppiPrinterX)/float(ppiScreenX)



        # Now adjust if the real page size is reduced (such as when

        # drawing on a scaled wx.MemoryDC in the Print Preview.)  If

        # page width == DC width then nothing changes, otherwise we

        # scale down for the DC.

        pw, ph = self.GetPageSizePixels()

        dw, dh = dc.GetSize()

        scale = logScale * float(dw)/float(pw)



        # Set the DC's scale.

        dc.SetUserScale(scale, scale)



        # Find the logical units per millimeter (for calculating the

        # margins)

        self.numPages = 1
        self.logUnitsMM = float(ppiPrinterX)/(logScale*25.4)

    def OnPreparePrinting(self):

        # calculate the number of pages

        dc = self.GetDC()

        self.CalculateScale(dc)

    def OnPrintPage(self, page):
        dc = self.GetDC()
        dc.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.TELETYPE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

        texto  = "┌─────────┬──────────┐\n"
        texto += "│columna1 │ columna2 │\n"
        texto += "├─────────┼──────────┤\n"
        texto += "│dato1    │ dato2    │\n"
        texto += "├─────────┼──────────┤\n"
        texto += "│dato3    │ dato4    │\n"
        texto += "└─────────┴──────────┘"

        dc.DrawText(texto, self.logUnitsMM*15, self.logUnitsMM*15)

        return True

class PrintFrameworkSample(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self)

        # initialize the print data and set some default values

        self.pdata = wx.PrintData()

        self.pdata.SetPaperId(wx.PAPER_A4)

        self.pdata.SetOrientation(wx.PORTRAIT)


    def OnPrint(self):#, evt):

        data = wx.PrintDialogData(self.pdata)

        printer = wx.Printer(data)

        printout = TextDocPrintout()

        useSetupDialog = True

        if not printer.Print(self, printout, useSetupDialog) and printer.GetLastError() == wx.PRINTER_ERROR:

            wx.MessageBox(

                "Hubo un problema al imprimir.\n"

                "Su impresora está configurada correctamente?",

                "Error al Imprimir", wx.OK)

        else:
            data = printer.GetPrintDialogData()

            self.pdata = wx.PrintData(data.GetPrintData()) # force a copy

        printout.Destroy()

app=wx.App(False)
PrintFrameworkSample().OnPrint()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: We're going to need a bit more code than "I use `wx.Font`"

Comment: I will do my best to rewrite the question and include the necessary information.

Comment: Ready. I hope to works.

Comment: On my Linux box this works. To be more specific, you could either add a `wx.FontDialog` to choose the specific font or be specific when you define the font to be used i.e. add `faceName` to the `SetFont` command. `dc.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, faceName="Monospace"))`. Using whatever facename works on your OS.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried what you proposed and it worked for me! I have Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the font facename can force the issue:
`dc.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, faceName="Monospace"))`
However there is a `FontEnumerator` available, which can be used to select a suitable font from those available.
Here is an example of its use, looking for fixed width fonts.

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        fonts = wx.FontEnumerator()
        fonts.EnumerateFacenames(wx.FONTENCODING_SYSTEM,fixedWidthOnly=True)
        font_list = fonts.GetFacenames(wx.FONTENCODING_SYSTEM,fixedWidthOnly=True)

        list_text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Face names:")
        self.font = wx.ListBox(self, -1, size=(200, 500), choices=font_list)
        self.font_size = wx.SpinCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, min=6, max=50, initial=16)
        self.sample = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Sample ")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(list_text, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.font, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.font_size, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.sample, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.font.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnSelect)
        self.font_size.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnSelect)
        self.font.SetSelection(0)
        self.font_size.SetToolTip('Select font size')
        self.OnSelect(None)

    def OnSelect(self, evt):
        facename = self.font.GetStringSelection()
        size = self.font_size.GetValue()
        font = wx.Font(size, family=wx.DEFAULT, style=wx.NORMAL, weight=wx.NORMAL, underline=False, faceName=facename)
        self.sample.SetLabel(facename)
        self.sample.SetFont(font)
        self.Refresh()

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,title="Fixed Width FontEnumerator", size=(800,600))
        panel = MyPanel(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: While I was waiting for your answer I forgot the question. Apologies. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing it using the **triple quote**? Please, try this and tell me:

```
texto  = '''
┌─────────┬──────────┐
│columna1 │ columna2 │
├─────────┼──────────┤
│dato1    │ dato2    │
├─────────┼──────────┤
│dato3    │ dato4    │
└─────────┴──────────┘
'''
print(texto)
```

Good luck!

Comment: The problem was already solved and while I was waiting for that person to write the solution, I forgot the question. Apologies.

Comment: I don't think triple quotes will make any difference.